# Moving an swfobject around in an HTML page

Tags: android, html, position, swfobject

I'm quite new to developing (this is my first project, I'm learning as I go) so there may be a very simple answer to this!

I'm creating an android application for radio station, written in HTML using the Appmobi XDK. The station uses a shoutcast address, but I know that android struggles to deal with this so I embedded the shoutcast IP inside a flash player template div that I found online. However, I cannot get the div to change position on the HTML page, it always stays at the top left or else disappears. I try using the style TOP: LEFT etc and also the align:center, neither of which worked. So I'm wondering does anyone know how i can move it to where I want it on the page.

I have provided the HTML for the div and code below. if anyone knows how to fix this I would be greatly obliged! thank  you!

```
  "<div id="container"> <a href="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">Get the Flash Player</a> to see this player.
 <a href="http://www.shoutcheap.com/shoutcast/">shoutcast server hosting</a>
 <a href="http://www.shoutcheap.com/icecast/">icecast server hosting</a></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.shoutcheap.com/flashplayer/swfobject.js"></script>
 <script type="text/css" style= "TOP:700; LEFT:250; ">
 var s1 = new SWFObject("http://www.shoutcheap.com/flashplayer/player.swf" ,
 "ply","250","50","9","#FFFFFF");
 s1.addParam("allowfullscreen","true");
 s1.addParam("allowscriptaccess","always");
 s1.addParam("flashvars",
 "file=http://50.7.244.222:10074/;stream.nsv&type=mp3&volume=50&autostart=true");
 s1.write("container");"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your style

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 700px; // distance from the top of the page
margin-left: -125px; // subtract half the width of the document to align center
```